# IHTMLAttribute how to get untrimmed value property

Tags: c#, dom, ihtmldocument2

I am casting an IHTMLDomNode attribute to IHTMLDOMAttribute

```
IHTMLAttributeCollection attributes = (IHTMLAttributeCollection)childDomElement.attributes;
```

the problem is that when I use IHTMLDOMAttribute value property to get the value of a particular element node, it seems to internally trim the value string. So for example if an attribute value like class=' wrong' is selected, then the attribute value would retunr 'wrong', which is wrong because it should have the blank space. Any idea how to get the right name?

Comment: are you using any type of Looping or Enumeration to get the attribute's expected value..? for example are you also doing anything like this.. this -- iElement.innerHTML = "<span attr1='somevalue'
attr2='somevalue' attrN='...'>markup</span>"

Comment: Yes I am iterating with an enumeration over all attributes. However, when I get the value property of an attribute it would be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help but from what I am understanding you could do something like the following.. here is what I would use in my own special case for checking or getting at Attributes. feel free to use this code to help point you in the right direction

```
IHTMLAttributeCollection myAttrColl =
(IHTMLAttributeCollection)myNode.attributes;
IHTMLDOMAttribute myAttr;

foreach myAttr in myAttrColl
{
  if (myAttr.specified) //do something
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the value of a particular element is trimmed. Please read the example.